# Need a Stack Exchange site for discussion about Hinduism

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I think in this network (Stack Exchange) there should be a site for  Q&A about Hinduism! I saw two pages for Christianity and Islam. Hinduism is the third  largest religion and having 115cr+ followers. Then why not for Hinduism?

Comment: For that, you need to knock at the doors of [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), *where users come together to build new Q&A sites. New site ideas are proposed, discussed, and the best go on to beta.*

Comment: We have [a proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism?referrer=QLZeFNGkjEKJw-d7A6Mm7A2). Please commit to it and ask interested friends to do the same, as time is running out (we only have 5 months to go).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is already a [Proposal for that on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) – the staging site for new SE Q&A sites.

You can commit to it and help shaping the content of that future site.

---

**Update:** [Hinduism Stack Exchange](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions) is in public beta for some time now.